# how to set values for variables inside setState if those variables are null

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Here I set default values for the variables inside the `state > currentWeather` like as following example, then again i set dynamic values for those variables to work for user search terms, when app open static values are not displayed, how I can fix that?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentWeather: {
      currentLocation: 'Colombo',
      currentDate: new Date(),
      currentTempreture: 28.3,
      currentWeatherLabel: 'rain',
      currentWind: 1.5,
      currentHumidity: 60
    }
  };

  getWeather = async e => {
    this.setState({
      currentTempreture: data.main.temp,
      currentLocation: data.name,
      currentWind: data.wind.speed,
      currentHumidity: data.main.humidity,
      currentWeatherLabel: data.weather[0].description
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="bsec" className="b-color body-sec">
        <div className="main-wrapper">
          <MainWidget
            location={this.state.currentLocation}
            date={this.state.currentDate}
            tempreture={this.state.currentTempreture}
            label={this.state.currentWeatherLabel}
            wind={this.state.currentWind}
            humidity={this.state.currentHumidity}
            pressure={this.state.currentPressure}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do some data validation as `data.main.temp` will break your application if `main` is `undefined` or data is null.

```
this.setState({

  currentTempreture: data && data.main && data.main.temp || 'default value',    
  currentLocation: data && data.name || 'default value',
  currentWind: data && data.wind && data.wind.speed || 'default value',
  currentHumidity: data && data.main && data.main.humidity || 'default value',
  currentWeatherLabel: data && data.wat && data.weather[0].description || 'default value',

});
```

**For example:**

with data validation

```js
const data = {}

console.log(data && data.main && data.main.temp || 'default value')
```

Without data validation

```js
const data = {}

console.log(data.main.temp ? data.main.temp : 'default value')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is very helpful!

Comment: You should explicitly check values for `null` where needed, as `0` or `''` would also represent false.

Comment: @PrithvirajSahu no I don't have to, this check `data && data.main && data.main.temp || 'default value'` takes care of that.

Comment: @rajitha128 please create a simple working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState({
 currentTempreture: data.main.temp ? data.main.temp:"static values",    
 currentLocation: data.name ? data.name :"static values",
 currentWind:data.wind.speed ? data.wind.speed : "static values",
 currentHumidity: data.main.humidity?data.main.humidity:"static values",
 currentWeatherLabel: data.weather.length>0 ? 
 data.weather[0].description : [],

});
```

like this you can set

Comment: Thanks for your idea it is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to update the state variables if they are null. You can try this -

```
this.setState(state => ({
  currentTempreture: state.currentTempreture === null ? data.main.temp : state.currentTempreture,    
  currentLocation: state.currentLocation === null ? data.name : state.currentLocation,
  currentWind: state.currentWind === null ? data.wind.speed : state.currentWind,
  currentHumidity: state.currentHumidity === null ? data.main.humidity : state.currentHumidity,
  currentWeatherLabel: state.currentWeatherLabel === null ? data.weather[0].description : state.currentWeatherLabel,
}));
```

Comment: he/she wants to set static values, if values in `data` are null. and you are not validating `data.main.temp`  what if `data.main` is null or undefined?

Comment: Okay... I misunderstood the question. Thank you @julekgwa. In that case, your answer is the one I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

as [julekgwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858806/julekgwa) mention you will need to validate your data or your application will break, the following example makes use of the get method of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) to accomplish the result:

```
this.setState({
 currentTempreture: _.get(data, 'main.temp', "default value"),    
 currentLocation: _.get(data, 'name', "default value"),
 currentWind: _.get(data, 'wind.speed', "default value"),
 currentHumidity: _.get(data, 'main.humidity', "default value"),
 currentWeatherLabel: _.size(data.weather) > 0 ?  data.weather[0].description : [],
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that your state is an object, so that you can do like:

```
if (Object.keys(your state).length) == 0 { 
      // Do something here 
}
```

Or try with `your.state === null`